# How to annotate E-Mails in thunderbird

Tags: linux, email, thunderbird

For example if I ask someone something per email and the person phones back, it would be nice if I could associate my notes of this conservation (and the plain fact that the question was discussed via phone) to my original email in a convenient way.

Is there a way to achieve this in thunderbird? If not is there any other email client for linux which has such a feature.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it's the best way, but I use [XNote++](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/xnotepp/)

It allows you to get note about each e-mail in a convenient way.